# jquery code changes CSS but I want to fire a function instead

Tags: jquery, function

I've got a line of code which waits for #total to increase by 1 and changes the CSS when that happens.

```
$('#total_shares').html(parseFloat($('#total').html())+1).css({
   //Changes CSS of #total
});
```

I'd like to know - if I want to retain the same code but instead of .css(); fire a function instead where I would have many more options rather than changing CSS alone. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, use `.each()`, like this:

```
$('#total_shares').html(parseFloat($('#total').html())+1).each(function() {
   $(this).css({left: 50});//example css change
   //Changes CSS of #total
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#total_shares').html(parseFloat($('#total').html())+1).each(function(idx, domElement){
   var $jQueryElement = $(domElement);
   // DO ANYTHING YOU WISH 
});
```

This way, you can change the initial selector and still retain all functionality for every matched element.

Otherwise if you **know** you only have 1 element (which is your case) you can do:

```
var $jQueryElement = $('#total_shares').html(parseFloat($('#total').html())+1);
// DO ANYTHING YOU WISH with the matched element
```